# SwiftUI Navigation link doesn't work when filtering ForEach

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a segmented picker to filter the list rows inside a ForEach but the NavigationLinks stop working when filtering, they have the tap animation but never change view. I am using CoreData for the deck. When I tap the rows in Standard they work normally, then I tap Wild and the NavigationLinks still work but then when I go back to standard this is what happens:

[image]

This is the code I have:

```
 ForEach(decks.filter{$0.format == formats[selectedFormat]}, id: \.self) { deck in
                    HStack {
                        ZStack {
                            DeckRow(deck: deck)
                            NavigationLink(destination: DeckView()) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided code is not testable, but by reading assume the reason of issue is in equal navigation links, try the following (that will result in updating links on filtering)

```
ZStack {
    DeckRow(deck: deck)
    NavigationLink(destination: DeckView()) {
        EmptyView()
    }.id(deck)        // << here !!
}
```

or, as it would be expected, make that `DeckView` dependent on `deck`, like `DeckView(model: deck)`, which also make each navigation link unique and refreshable on filter.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give "deck" also to your deckview so it can show the right deckview

Comment: and by the way, the best way to represent your code is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example